# Passenger with nginx: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

There is only one version of Ruby installed, and I have run `gem install bundler && bundle install`.

## nginx conf

```
passenger_root /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/http/myrailsapp/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
}
```

## Error Log

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.52/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 10):

I have been solving similar issue.

My problem was in configuration of `passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;` Which points to the incorrect version. My solution was to set the path to output of command `which ruby`

On the server I use rvm. But there are aslo other instalations of ruby.

At first try to test the environment. Go to the application directory and run `passenger start`. This will show you you, if the server is ready to run the app. Fix the errors...

If the message still says that

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

run `gem install bundler` and re-check.

Then set up the path in NGINX to path from `which ruby` command and restart the appllication.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `passenger_root` value. Like [here in doc](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#inserting_passenger_root_for_apt)

For example my nginx config:

```
...
  passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
...
```

Comment: `passenger-config --root` gave me same thing as `passenger_root` value

Answer (score 0):

The phusion passenger could not find the ruby path, see if the ruby path is correct, or if the symbolic link was removed in the server update or other reason.

CentOS 7
Ruby 2.6.3
Rbenv

```
which ruby
# ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby # old ruby
sudo ln -s ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby /usr/bin/ruby # 2.6.3
 /usr/bin/ruby -v 
# ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
sudo service nginx restart
```